# Rule based Classfication Algorithm on a job finder

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

Excuse for asking, but I am trying to make a searching  system using rule based classification algorithm, but the problem is I can't seem to find out how to implement it.

I had an idea in my head. First, generate the data using php select statement and then, test all the data if it matches with the user's input. Am I getting it correct, or is there something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are going to create your rules based on your input and then send data to the search query either in post or in URL ( Prefer in URL) . You form would be something like this
[image]

Four rules for assumption upon send it would create search URL like

[image]

You will create a search function something like this

```
public function search_item($data,$per_page,$offset=0)
{
    $term_q='';
    $loc_q='';
    $pur_q='';
    if($per_page==0)
    {
        $limit_q='';
    }
    else
    {
        $limit_q='LIMIT '.$offset.','.$per_page;
    }

    if($data['keyword']!='')
    {$term_q='AND (property.title LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['keyword']).'%" OR property.description LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['keyword']).'%" OR property.city LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['keyword']).'%") ';}
    if($data['location']!='')
    {
        $loc_q=' AND (property.location LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['location']).'%" OR property.title LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['location']).'%" OR property.description LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['location']).'%" OR property.city LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['location']).'%") ';
    }
    if($data['purpose']!='')
    {
        $pur_q=' AND property.purpose LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['purpose']).'%" ';
    }
    $data=$this->db->query("SELECT property.*, users.name as posted_by, property_types.name as property_type
                      from property
                      inner join users on users.id=property.posted_by
                      inner join property_types on property_types.id=property.type

                      WHERE property.status='approved'
                      {$term_q}
                      {$loc_q}
                      {$pur_q}
                      {$limit_q}
                      ")->result_array();
    //print_r($this->db->last_query());exit;
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
        $data[$i]['images']=$this->db->query('SELECT * from property_images WHERE property_images.property_id='.$data[$i]['id'])->result_array();
    }

    return $data;
    //return $this->db->last_query();
}
```

Done mind the syntax, its in Codeigniter framework, but I will explain it to you . The data parameter in the function is what you are getting from your URL, sent to this function taken from $_REQUEST. The $per_page and $offset are for pagination.

Now the search algorithm is nothing but a big SELECT query with chunks of small clauses which define the rules based on which your data is filtered. IF you see in the function

```
$term_q='';
$loc_q='';
$pur_q='';
if($per_page==0)
{
    $limit_q='';
}
else
{
    $limit_q='LIMIT '.$offset.','.$per_page;
}

if($data['keyword']!='')
{$term_q='AND (property.title LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['keyword']).'%" OR property.description LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['keyword']).'%" OR property.city LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['keyword']).'%") ';}
if($data['location']!='')
{
    $loc_q=' AND (property.location LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['location']).'%" OR property.title LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['location']).'%" OR property.description LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['location']).'%" OR property.city LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['location']).'%") ';
}
if($data['purpose']!='')
{
    $pur_q=' AND property.purpose LIKE "%'.addslashes($data['purpose']).'%" ';
}
```

Above section is defining all the rules which are then embedded in the main query to get the filtered data. So you see its very easy, all you have to do is to define your rules. Get them in your input either from some form or by sending them yourself and then process those rules to create query and in the end execute that query to get results from your Database.

Comment: Yeah, I tried suggesting searching the data through sql but my adviser said that I should stick to the algorithm, so I assumed that the idea was wrong... I don't know maybe it's just me.